# my __init is called but not getting call for probe

Tags: module, kernel, kernel-module, clr-module-initializer

I am enabling the pinctrl driver in the raspberry linux and I tried something and enabled it.

But what happened is, the __init is calling but the probe is not calling by the linux.

My code is

this is the probe

```
static int bcm2835_pinctrl_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)

{
struct device *dev = &pdev->dev;
struct device_node *np = dev->of_node;
struct bcm2835_pinctrl *pc;
struct resource iomem;
int err, i;

BUILD_BUG_ON(ARRAY_SIZE(bcm2835_gpio_pins) != BCM2835_NUM_GPIOS);

BUILD_BUG_ON(ARRAY_SIZE(bcm2835_gpio_groups) != BCM2835_NUM_GPIOS);

pc = devm_kzalloc(dev, sizeof(*pc), GFP_KERNEL);
if (!pc)
    return -ENOMEM;

platform_set_drvdata(pdev, pc);
pc->dev = dev;

err = of_address_to_resource(np, 0, &iomem);
if (err) {
    dev_err(dev, "could not get IO memory\n");
    return err;
}

pc->base = devm_ioremap_resource(dev, &iomem);
if (IS_ERR(pc->base))
    return PTR_ERR(pc->base);

pc->gpio_chip = bcm2835_gpio_chip;
pc->gpio_chip.dev = dev;

pc->irq_domain = irq_domain_add_linear(np, BCM2835_NUM_GPIOS,
        &irq_domain_simple_ops, NULL);
if (!pc->irq_domain) {
    dev_err(dev, "could not create IRQ domain\n");
    return -ENOMEM;
}

for (i = 0; i < BCM2835_NUM_GPIOS; i++) {
    int irq = irq_create_mapping(pc->irq_domain, i);
    irq_set_lockdep_class(irq, &gpio_lock_class);
    irq_set_chip_and_handler(irq, &bcm2835_gpio_irq_chip,
            handle_simple_irq);
    irq_set_chip_data(irq, pc);
    set_irq_flags(irq, IRQF_VALID);
}

for (i = 0; i < BCM2835_NUM_BANKS; i++) {
    unsigned long events;
    unsigned offset;
    int len;
    char *name;

    /* clear event detection flags */
    bcm2835_gpio_wr(pc, GPREN0 + i * 4, 0);
    bcm2835_gpio_wr(pc, GPFEN0 + i * 4, 0);
    bcm2835_gpio_wr(pc, GPHEN0 + i * 4, 0);
    bcm2835_gpio_wr(pc, GPLEN0 + i * 4, 0);
    bcm2835_gpio_wr(pc, GPAREN0 + i * 4, 0);
    bcm2835_gpio_wr(pc, GPAFEN0 + i * 4, 0);

    /* clear all the events */
    events = bcm2835_gpio_rd(pc, GPEDS0 + i * 4);
    for_each_set_bit(offset, &events, 32)
        bcm2835_gpio_wr(pc, GPEDS0 + i * 4, BIT(offset));

    pc->irq[i] = irq_of_parse_and_map(np, i);
    pc->irq_data[i].pc = pc;
    pc->irq_data[i].bank = i;
    spin_lock_init(&pc->irq_lock[i]);

    len = strlen(dev_name(pc->dev)) + 16;
    name = devm_kzalloc(pc->dev, len, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!name)
        return -ENOMEM;
    snprintf(name, len, "%s:bank%d", dev_name(pc->dev), i);

    err = devm_request_irq(dev, pc->irq[i],
        bcm2835_gpio_irq_handler, IRQF_SHARED,
        name, &pc->irq_data[i]);
    if (err) {
        dev_err(dev, "unable to request IRQ %d\n", pc->irq[i]);
        return err;
    }
}

err = gpiochip_add(&pc->gpio_chip);
if (err) {
    dev_err(dev, "could not add GPIO chip\n");
    return err;
}

pc->pctl_dev = pinctrl_register(&bcm2835_pinctrl_desc, dev, pc);
if (!pc->pctl_dev) {
    err = gpiochip_remove(&pc->gpio_chip);
    return err;
}

pc->gpio_range = bcm2835_pinctrl_gpio_range;
pc->gpio_range.base = pc->gpio_chip.base;
pc->gpio_range.gc = &pc->gpio_chip;
pinctrl_add_gpio_range(pc->pctl_dev, &pc->gpio_range);

return 0;
}

static struct of_device_id bcm2835_pinctrl_match[] = {
{ .compatible = "brcm,bcm2835-gpio" },
{}
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, bcm2835_pinctrl_match);

static struct platform_driver bcm2835_pinctrl_driver = {
    .probe = bcm2835_pinctrl_probe,
    .remove = bcm2835_pinctrl_remove,
    .driver = {
        .name = MODULE_NAME,
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,
        .of_match_table = bcm2835_pinctrl_match,
    },
};


static int __init bcm2835_pinctrl_init(void)
{
    return platform_driver_register(&bcm2835_pinctrl_driver);
}

static void __exit bcm2835_pinctrl_exit(void)
{
    platform_driver_unregister(&bcm2835_pinctrl_driver);
}

module_init(bcm2835_pinctrl_init);
module_exit(bcm2835_pinctrl_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("Chris Boot, Simon Arlott, Stephen Warren");

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("BCM2835 Pin control driver");

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Can anyone help me out this?

I am not getting where i did wrong and why the probe is not calling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem is that i forgot to add the driver structure in the board file.

After adding that i am getting call to the probe